# Calling Jquery Login Popup if Login Check Fails

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have the following jquery login form which can be called on a button click, but also I want it to be called when a php login check is false. What can I add to it to make it callable by php?

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

             $(document).ready(function() {
$('a.login-window, a.log').click(function() {

            //Getting the variable's value from a link 
    var loginBox = $(this).attr('href');

    //Fade in the Popup
    $(loginBox).fadeIn(300);

    //Set the center alignment padding + border see css style
    var popMargTop = ($(loginBox).height() + 24) / 2; 
    var popMargLeft = ($(loginBox).width() + 24) / 2; 

    $(loginBox).css({ 
        'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
        'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
    });

    // Add the mask to body
    $('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
    $('#mask').fadeIn(300);

    return false;
});

// When clicking on the button close or the mask layer the popup closed
$('a.close, #mask').live('click', function() { 
  $('#mask , .login-popup').fadeOut(300 , function() {
    $('#mask').remove();  
}); 
return false;
});
});
             </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setup a call to trigger the login form open if the login request was invalid:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.login-window, a.log').click(function () {
        //Getting the variable's value from a link 
        var loginBox = $(this).attr('href');

        //Fade in the Popup
        $(loginBox).fadeIn(300);

        //Set the center alignment padding + border see css style
        var popMargTop = ($(loginBox).height() + 24) / 2;
        var popMargLeft = ($(loginBox).width() + 24) / 2;

        $(loginBox).css({
            'margin-top': -popMargTop,
            'margin-left': -popMargLeft
        });

        // Add the mask to body
        $('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
        $('#mask').fadeIn(300);

        return false;
    });

    // When clicking on the button close or the mask layer the popup closed
    $('a.close, #mask').live('click', function () {
        $('#mask , .login-popup').fadeOut(300, function () {
            $('#mask').remove();
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Then, somewhere that's at least *after* that previous `$.ready()` ran (not setup, *executed it's handler*), do:

```
if ($php_login_request === true && $php_user_authenticated !== true) { 
    echo "<script>$('a.login-window, a.log').trigger('click');</script>";
}
```

I just marked those `$php_` variables so you would get that those need to be performed on the server, obviously at some point between the authentication step and the end of the `' tag.